# How can i update an array from an object as y delete another object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have to models Employee and Game. Games have a property named employees that is an array of ids of existing employees. I am trying to update the array as i delete an employee. For example if i delete an employee with `id` of `2346`, then i want to pull from each game object in their array of employees, the id of the employee i am deleting. For that i am trying to do a pre hook for deleteOne function.

My employees.js (controller)

```
exports.deleteEmployee = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const employee = await Employee.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

  if (!employee) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`Employee not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );
  }

  await employee.deleteOne();

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    data: {},
  });
});
```

And this is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['employee', 'manager'],
    default: 'employee',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
});

employeeSchema.pre('deleteOne', async function (next) {
  try {
    const employeeId = this._id;

    await mongoose
      .model('Game')
      .updateMany(
        { employees: employeeId },
        { $pull: { employees: employeeId } }
      );
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);

module.exports = Employee;
```

The employee is being deleted correctly but the employees property of the Game is not being updated.
The id of the delete employee it is still in each game.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Could you display the value of `employeeId` variable in your pre-hook `deleteOne` function?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
const employee = await Employee.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
```

and then

```
await employee.deleteOne();
```

in your `employees.js` controller so delete the second one from your code.

The method `findByIdAndDelete` is a shorthand for `findOneAndDelete({ _id: id })` as per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndDelete()). That means `findByIdAndDelete` triggers `findOneAndDelete` not `deleteOne`. Try changing your `pre` hook to:

```
employeeSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete', async function (next) {
   try {
      const employeeId = this._id;
```